# Failed to load servlet class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer

Tags: spring, maven, jsf, servlets, jersey

The context here is that I am trying to configure the project to run with Spring JSF and deploy a web-service using Jersey using Maven as a dependency manager.
However, as I try to run the project, the log told me that servlet class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer is failed to load. But I looked into the jar files and I saw that there is the class inside. 
I did search for many way to fix it but it seems like not my case. 
Below is my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>weservice</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>weservice Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <!-- JUnit dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JSF dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Java Servlet dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring 4.0.4 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>2.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Jersey dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.15</version>         
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>weservice</finalName>
</build>
```

And this is my [web.xml](http://pastebin.com/WCYaVne9) file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <description>JAX-RS Tools Generated - Do not modify</description>
        <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.aavn.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/jaxrs/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Error Log :

```
    !ENTRY org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.582
!MESSAGE 
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.582
!MESSAGE Failed to load servlet class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.582
!MESSAGE org.apache.geronimo.common.DeploymentException: Failed to load servlet class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.582
!MESSAGE    at org.apache.geronimo.jaxws.builder.AdvancedWARWebServiceFinder.getPortInfo(AdvancedWARWebServiceFinder.java:169)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.582
!MESSAGE    at org.apache.geronimo.jaxws.builder.AdvancedWARWebServiceFinder.discoverPOJOWebServices(AdvancedWARWebServiceFinder.java:143)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at org.apache.geronimo.jaxws.builder.AdvancedWARWebServiceFinder.discoverWebServices(AdvancedWARWebServiceFinder.java:44)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at org.apache.geronimo.jaxws.builder.AdvancedWARWebServiceFinder.discoverWebServices(AdvancedWARWebServiceFinder.java:37)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at org.apache.geronimo.jaxws.builder.WARWebServiceFinder.discoverWebServices(WARWebServiceFinder.java:51)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at org.apache.geronimo.jaxws.builder.WARWebServiceFinder.discoverWebServices(WARWebServiceFinder.java:28)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at org.apache.geronimo.jaxws.builder.JAXWSServiceBuilder.discoverWebServices(JAXWSServiceBuilder.java:245)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at org.apache.geronimo.jaxws.builder.JAXWSServiceBuilder.findWebServices(JAXWSServiceBuilder.java:103)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.deployment.TomcatModuleBuilder.postInitContext(TomcatModuleBuilder.java:454)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at org.apache.geronimo.web25.deployment.AbstractWebModuleBuilder.initContext(AbstractWebModuleBuilder.java:437)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at org.apache.geronimo.j2ee.deployment.SwitchingModuleBuilder.initContext(SwitchingModuleBuilder.java:168)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at org.apache.geronimo.j2ee.deployment.EARConfigBuilder.buildConfiguration(EARConfigBuilder.java:686)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:281)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:145)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.ReflectionMethodInvoker.invoke(ReflectionMethodInvoker.java:34)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanOperation.invoke(GBeanOperation.java:131)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.invoke(GBeanInstance.java:883)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicKernel.invoke(BasicKernel.java:245)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.KernelGBean.invoke(KernelGBean.java:344)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor112.invoke(Unknown Source)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.ReflectionMethodInvoker.invoke(ReflectionMethodInvoker.java:34)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanOperation.invoke(GBeanOperation.java:131)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.invoke(GBeanInstance.java:883)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicKernel.invoke(BasicKernel.java:245)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at org.apache.geronimo.system.jmx.MBeanGBeanBridge.invoke(MBeanGBeanBridge.java:172)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1427)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor64.invoke(Unknown Source)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:202)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:199)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:198)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:567)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.access$400(TCPTransport.java:619)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:684)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at org.apache.geronimo.hook.equinox.GeronimoClassLoader.loadClass(GeronimoClassLoader.java:85)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1207)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    at org.apache.geronimo.jaxws.builder.AdvancedWARWebServiceFinder.getPortInfo(AdvancedWARWebServiceFinder.java:160)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.core 4 0 2015-02-11 13:15:56.583
!MESSAGE    ... 57 more
```

If there is any other information you guys need, please let me know.

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you paste the full stack trace please?

Comment: Don't use anything `com.sun.jersey` with Jersey 2. See [here for the correct Jersey-Spring dep](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/spring.html). The support is for Spring 3, so I don't know how it will work with Spring 4. Here's a complete [hello-world](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.15/examples/helloworld-spring-webapp/pom.xml)

Comment: @almasshaikh : Is it to export the full entry from Eclipse Error logs? I did export but it kinda too long so I want to ask you for instruction. Thank you.

Comment: @peeskillet Thank you for your help, I will try now and let you know. I will find out if it will work with Spring 4.

Comment: @almasshaikh this is the error entry I exported. http://pastebin.com/C2PwZ3Lf

Comment: @peeskillet I did change Jersey-Spring dep but it still pop the same error. I dont know if it could be the Spring version or something. But it just failed to load the class.

Comment: For better help, post the error here

Comment: The cause is stated. The  class can't be found. Did you check to see if all the jars are in the `WEB-INF/lib` in the exploded war in your server.

Comment: I did check that the jar file is in the libraries and the class is exist in the library. What do you mean by 'the exploded war in your server'? 
I export my project to a WAR file and import it back to Eclipse to see if there is any jar under WEB-INF/lib but there is nothing under it? Is it wrong and I missed something?

Comment: By exploded war I mean when the .war file is tranported to the server, it gets expanded into a folder with the same name as the war. That is the exploded way. If you see that folder, in it there is the WEB-INF/lib. If there's nothing there, then all your jar dependencies aren't getting exported with the war

Comment: What server are you using? And how do you run it?

Comment: I'm using Geronimo 3.0.1 as Tomcat 7.0 included.

Comment: Try to build the app. Then manually copy the created .war file to the webapp folder of the server. Then start the server. See if the libs are in the war

Comment: Actually, eclipse with geronimo will deploy the project automatically but when publishing to the server, the error pop up and terminate the process. Even if I export a WAR file and manually deploy to geronimo server, it still pops the same error.

Comment: Are you using JSF, JAX-RS and Spring in a sane way?

Comment: @Tiny: Ah yes, I'm using JSF, JAX-RS and Spring at a time